# Simon game challenge

Tags: javascript, html

I want to compare the recent user pattern("userPattern") with the randomly generated pattern("gamePattern").and if userPattern eual to gamepattern I want to enter into next level.
Ho to do that? now I have done up to responding to the user's click.

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Press A Key To Start</h1>
    <main>
      <button type="button" id="green" class="green box"></button>
      <button type="button" id="red" class="red box"></button>
      <button type="button" id="yellow" class="yellow box"></button>
      <button type="button" id="blue" class="blue box"></button>
    </main>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My JS code:

```
var color = ["green", "red", "yellow", "blue"];

var gamePattern = [];
var userPattern = [];

var level = 0;

function newSequence() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var colorChosen = color[randomNumber];
  var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + colorChosen + ".mp3");
  audio.play();
  $("#" + colorChosen)
    .fadeOut(250)
    .fadeIn(250);
  gamePattern.push(colorChosen);

  $("h1").text("Level " + level);
  level++;
  var userColorChosen;
  for (var i = 0; i < $("button").length; i++) {
    $("#" + color[i]).click(function () {
      userColorChosen = this.id;
      userPattern.push(userColorChosen);
      var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + userColorChosen + ".mp3");
      audio.play();
      $("#" + userColorChosen)
        .fadeOut(100)
        .fadeIn(100);
    });
  }
}

var call = true;
$(document).keypress(function () {
  if (call === true) {
    newSequence();
  }
  call = false;
});
```

Please help me.

Comment: What you seem to be asking is "how do I compare two arrays of strings?" Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript). Next time, it would be helpful if you could narrow the code in the question so there wasn't so much for people to read to get to the core problem.

Answer (score 0):

My answer using Jquery for Simon Game:

```
var color = ["green", "red", "yellow", "blue"];

var gamePattern = [];
var userPattern = [];

var level = 0;

$("button").click(function () {
  var userColorChosen = $(this).attr("id");
  userPattern.push(userColorChosen);
  var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + userColorChosen + ".mp3");
  audio.play();
  $("#" + userColorChosen)
    .fadeOut(100)
    .fadeIn(100);
  checkAnswer(userPattern.length - 1);
});

function checkAnswer(currentLevel) {
  if (userPattern[currentLevel] === gamePattern[currentLevel]) {
    if (userPattern.length === gamePattern.length) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        newSequence();
      }, 1000);
    }
  } else {
    $("h1").text("GAMEOVER");
    var audio = new Audio("sounds/wrong.mp3");
    audio.play();
    $("body").addClass("gameover");
    setTimeout(function () {
      $("body").removeClass("gameover");
    }, 100);
    startOver();
  }
}

function newSequence() {
  userPattern = [];
  level++;
  $("h1").text("Level " + level);
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  var colorChosen = color[randomNumber];
  gamePattern.push(colorChosen);
  var audio = new Audio("sounds/" + colorChosen + ".mp3");
  audio.play();
  $("#" + colorChosen)
    .fadeOut(250)
    .fadeIn(250);
}

var call = true;
$(document).keypress(function () {
  if (call === true) {
    newSequence();
    call = false;
  }
});

function startOver() {
  level = 0;
  gamePattern = [];
  call = true;
}
```